# Get only Top Drawable bound click in android EditText

Tags: android, kotlin, ontouchlistener, compound-drawables

I have implemented Custom EditText where I want to get all CompoundDrawables click.
I have got success to get Right and Left drawable click.

I have also get partial success to get the Top drawable click.

Here is my EditText Image:

[image: EditText Image]

**What I got:**
I got success to get the Click Event (TouchEvent) for Top area covered by RED rectangle. Here is the code for the same.

**Code:**

```
    override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        var bounds: Rect?
        if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            positionX = event.x.toInt()
            positionY = event.y.toInt()

        if (drawableTop != null) {
                bounds = drawableTop!!.bounds
                val xClickPosition: Int = positionX
                val yClickPosition: Int = positionY
                val extraClickingArea = 13

                if (xClickPosition >= (paddingLeft - extraClickingArea)) {
                    if (xClickPosition <= (width - paddingRight + extraClickingArea)) {
                        if (yClickPosition >= (paddingTop - extraClickingArea)) {
                            if (yClickPosition <= (paddingTop + bounds.height() + extraClickingArea)) {
                                   //I have to get Only Top drawable Bound here 
                       onDrawableClickListener!!.onClick(DrawablePosition.TOP)
                                    event.action = MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL
                                    return false
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }


    }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event)
    }
```

**What I want:**

But I only want click event covered by GREEN rectangle.

EditText Image:

[image: Normal EditText image]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please give down vote reason which helps me to improve my question.

Comment: That drawable is centered between the left and right paddings, and you have `bounds.width()` and `positionX`. It's just some relatively simple math to check if the x is within that. Off the cuff: `if (abs((width - paddingLeft - paddingRight) / 2 + paddingLeft - positionX) <= bound.width() / 2 + extraClickingArea)`. That could possibly be simplified a little.

Comment: Thanks Mike it works. I have tried some wrong equations to get X within it.